# MongoDb takes much time to updateDb with low amount of documents

Tags: mongodb, performance

Queries are returning slowly sometimes they take to around 2-3 secs to resolve.
We have only 0-10 documents they have a fields that contains an object.

It is a transient behavior, it happens only on first queries.

Comment: Is the server CPU free when you experience the performance issues, 
Are there any other process running in the same server,

Comment: check in your console (If you use Linux) top or htop

Comment: no i dont experience big CPU usage

Comment: we are under windows but we used the taskmanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got solution. We used in the connection string "localhost", and if mongodb look up the address it will wait a dns server timeout which casues the problem. After i changed the address to "127.0.0.1" format the nonresponsiveness disappeared.